# Accessing messages from android device with broken screen

Tags: lock-screens

I have an AG Chrome android phone. The screen is broken, I called the company, they cant help me as they do not make spares for the phone. I have important messages on the phone I need. The phone still comes on but I just cant use it because its a touch screen which is now unresponsive. Can anyone please help?
I tried most if not all suggestions on these pages without success. Im on windows xp?  Please.

Comment: is it rooted? have you tried accessing using ADB ?

Comment: Not rooted and adb did not work